# Slow postgres query when joining large tables

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have query that's performing pretty slowly. I believe that the issue is that I'm joining across several large tables, but I still would have expected better performance. Query and EXPLAIN ANALYZE below:

```
SELECT
    "m_advertsnapshot"."id",
    "m_advertsnapshot"."created",
    "m_advertsnapshot"."modified",
    "m_advertsnapshot"."snapshot_timestamp",
    "m_advertsnapshot"."source_name",
    COUNT(CASE m_advert.widget_listing_id IS NULL and m_advert.height IS NULL WHEN True THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS "adh_count_with_no_wl_and_missing_height",
    COUNT(CASE m_advert.widget_listing_id IS NULL and m_advert.height IS NOT NULL and m_advert.colour_id IS NOT NULL and m_advert.ctype IS NOT NULL WHEN True THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS "adh_count_with_no_wl_and_has_height_plate_ctype",
    COUNT(CASE m_advert.widget_listing_id IS NULL and m_advert.height IS NULL and m_advert.colour_id is NULL and m_advert.ctype is NULL  WHEN True THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS "adh_count_with_no_wl_and_missing_height_and_missing_plate_c268",
    COUNT("m_adverthistory"."id") AS "adh_count",
    COUNT(CASE m_advert.widget_listing_id IS NULL and m_advert.height IS NULL and m_advert.colour_id is NULL WHEN True THEN 1 ELSE null END) AS "adh_count_with_no_wl_and_missing_height_and_missing_plate",
    COUNT("m_advert"."widget_listing_id") AS "adh_count_with_wl"
FROM "m_advertsnapshot"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "m_adverthistory" ON ("m_advertsnapshot"."id" = "m_adverthistory"."advert_snapshot_id")
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "m_advert" ON ("m_adverthistory"."advert_id" = "m_advert"."id")
GROUP BY
    "m_advertsnapshot"."id",
    "m_advertsnapshot"."created",
    "m_advertsnapshot"."modified",
    "m_advertsnapshot"."snapshot_timestamp",
    "m_advertsnapshot"."source_name"
ORDER BY
    "m_advertsnapshot"."snapshot_timestamp" DESC



"Sort  (cost=796180.41..796180.90 rows=196 width=72) (actual time=18051.504..18051.519 rows=196 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: m_advertsnapshot.snapshot_timestamp"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 60kB"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=796170.99..796172.95 rows=196 width=72) (actual time=18051.330..18051.396 rows=196 loops=1)"
"        ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=227052.68..622950.33 rows=6298933 width=72) (actual time=2082.551..12166.226 rows=6298933 loops=1)"
"              Hash Cond: (m_adverthistory.advert_snapshot_id = m_advertsnapshot.id)"
"              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=227045.27..536332.59 rows=6298933 width=24) (actual time=2082.483..9971.996 rows=6298933 loops=1)"
"                    Hash Cond: (m_adverthistory.advert_id = m_advert.id)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on m_adverthistory  (cost=0.00..121858.33 rows=6298933 width=12) (actual time=0.003..1644.060 rows=6298933 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=202575.12..202575.12 rows=1332812 width=20) (actual time=2080.897..2080.897 rows=1332812 loops=1)"
"                          Buckets: 2048  Batches: 128  Memory Usage: 525kB"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on m_advert  (cost=0.00..202575.12 rows=1332812 width=20) (actual time=0.007..1564.220 rows=1332812 loops=1)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=4.96..4.96 rows=196 width=52) (actual time=0.062..0.062 rows=196 loops=1)"
"                    Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 17kB"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on m_advertsnapshot  (cost=0.00..4.96 rows=196 width=52) (actual time=0.004..0.030 rows=196 loops=1)"
"Total runtime: 18051.730 ms"
```

The query is taking 18 seconds using postgres 9.2. The table sizes are:

```
m_advertsnapshot - 196 rows
m_adverthistory - 6,298,933 rows
m_advert - 1,332,812 rows
```

DDLs:

```
-- m_advertsnapshot

CREATE TABLE m_advertsnapshot
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  snapshot_timestamp timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  source_name character varying(50),
  CONSTRAINT m_advertsnapshot_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT m_advertsnapshot_source_name_6a9a437077520191_uniq UNIQUE (source_name, snapshot_timestamp)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX m_advertsnapshot_snapshot_timestamp
  ON m_advertsnapshot
  USING btree
  (snapshot_timestamp);

-- m_adverthistory

CREATE TABLE m_adverthistory
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  advert_id integer NOT NULL,
  advert_snapshot_id integer NOT NULL,
  observed_timestamp timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT m_adverthistory_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT advert_id_refs_id_30735d9eef85241c FOREIGN KEY (advert_id)
      REFERENCES m_advert (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
  CONSTRAINT advert_snapshot_id_refs_id_55d3986f4f270624 FOREIGN KEY (advert_snapshot_id)
      REFERENCES m_advertsnapshot (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
  CONSTRAINT m_adverthistory_advert_id_13fa0dae39e78983_uniq UNIQUE (advert_id, advert_snapshot_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX m_adverthistory_advert_id
  ON m_adverthistory
  USING btree
  (advert_id);

CREATE INDEX m_adverthistory_advert_snapshot_id
  ON m_adverthistory
  USING btree
  (advert_snapshot_id);

-- m_advert

CREATE TABLE m_advert
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  widget_listing_id integer,
  height integer,
  ctype integer,
  colour_id integer,
  CONSTRAINT m_advert_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT "colour_id_refs_id_1e4e2dac0183b419" FOREIGN KEY (colour_id)
      REFERENCES colour ("id") MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
  CONSTRAINT widget_listing_id_refs_id_5a7e62d0d4f48013 FOREIGN KEY (widget_listing_id)
      REFERENCES m_widgetlisting (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,

)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX m_advert_advert_seller_id
  ON m_advert
  USING btree
  (advert_seller_id);

CREATE INDEX m_advert_colour_id
  ON m_advert
  USING btree
  (colour_id);

CREATE INDEX m_advert_widget_listing_id
  ON m_advert
  USING btree
  (widget_listing_id);
```

Any ideas on how to improve the performance of this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: To me it appears that id (or advert_id} should at least be part of the primary key of {m_advert, m_advertsnapshot} Do you *have* any primary keys or foreign keys in your schema? Please show us the DDL's

Comment: I added the DDLs. The joins are on primary/ foreign keys. These were generated by Django (though I don't think that makes a difference)

Comment: The schema looks reasonable (for the query you don't actually need the indexes, and some of the indexes are already covered by the FK constraints) The Junction table does not *need* a surrogate (but it won't harm). The real reason for your query being slow is that it needs **all the rows from all the tables** to compute the aggregates. If you need 100% of the data indexes cannot help very much. Adding an additional constraint (eg on snapshot_timestamp >= some_date) will probably cause a different plan that will use the indexes.

Comment: You might be able to get a boost by bumping `work_mem` up for this query, giving it more space to play with for its hashing and sorting. Try `SET work_mem = '50MB'` before the query and see if the plan or performance changes. *Do not* set this in `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: Have you tried changing the two indexes on History so that they havbe both fields: advert_id and advert_snapshot_id ? Having two indexes, with both fields (advert_id, advert_snapshot_id) and (advert_snapshot_id, advert_id) might help, since the second key could be picked up from the index itself.

Comment: Try to make simple subqueries. Once you get a good handle on the various steps and how long they take, you can combine them into one larger query.  In your example, I'd try do the join `snapshot` (196 rows) on `history` (6M rows) first. Then join the result on `advert`, then do your summary stats. Another thing is to compute extra columns with simple indicators in a subquery (e.g. `case when listing is null then 0 else 1 end as a`) and then add them appropriately with e.g. `sum(a*b*(1-c)) as foo,...`  In some instances (largish queries with tables over 10 billion rows) it has helped.

Comment: Thanks for all the ideas. I tried all of the above suggestions and didn't see any improvement, unfortunately. I think I'll have to denormalise

Comment: I revisited this and managed to dramatically increase the speed by including a restriction on snapshot_date (as wildplasser suggested) and adding two indexes: 1. m_advert (id, widget_listing_id, height, colour_id, ctype) 2. m_advertsnapshot (snapshot_timestamp, id, source_name, created, modified). That then converts all of the seq scans to index scans or index only scans. @wildplasser - your suggestion on the snapshot_timestamp constraint was most helpful, so I'll accept that if you post it as an answer

Comment: I seriously doubt if the answer will be useful for future readers, but I will copy-paste it into an answer box. Thank you, you're wellcome.

Comment: @wildplasser: If future readers interpret it as "don't try to report the universe", it's worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The schema looks reasonable (for the query you don't actually need the indexes, and some of the indexes are already covered by the FK constraints)
- The Junction table does not need a surrogate key (but it won't harm).
- The real reason for your query being slow is that it **needs all the rows** from **all the tables** to compute the aggregates. If you need 100% of the data, indexes cannot help very much.
- Adding an additional constraint (eg on snapshot_timestamp >= some_date) will probably cause a different plan that will use the indexes.