# Postgres optimizing join of 2 large tables

Tags: postgresql, join, timescaledb

I have 2 tables one with around 1m entries and other around 4m. I want to join these tables in a material view. But the material view creation time is taking too long ~4 hours.

[Slow postgres query when joining large tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15665112/slow-postgres-query-when-joining-large-tables)

i don't see the indexes being used, which is fine as per the answer in link above when join involves whole tables then indices dont help so much.

So what is the workaround? My tables have time-eries data. Would TimeScaleDB extension be of any help? Any other suggestion to improve the performance ?

Comment: Can you show the EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS), or at least the EXPLAIN, for the query?

Comment: It is a duplicate of the same question posted to another stackexchange community: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270862/postgres-optimizing-join-of-2-large-tables
Can you close one of them?

Comment: yes i posted at both places. Wasn't sure which place is the correct one. Sorry

Comment: To me it is more related to DBA than SO. So far there are no details in the question, but it seems to me there is a room for redesigning.

Comment: @k_rus, yeah I agree it is more DBA, hence i have explained the schema and the view in the other post. If you want you could mark this one as duplicate and please answer in the the other post on DBA if you suggest a redesign or some performance boost?

Comment: @jjanes, sorry I wasn't sure of the best place to post question so I posted both here and at DBA. Could you please make your recommendation here? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270862/postgres-optimizing-join-of-2-large-tables I have added the schema and explain results